# My ArcGIS hosted layers dont'show up in ArcGIS Online layers list

Tags: layers, arcgis-online, arcgis-online-webmap

I am using the free trial of ArcGIS, I would like to make a map online but my shapefile is too big and ArcGIS suggested to upload the file as an hosted layer.
I did and I can see the layer in my content tab:

[image]

But, when I go back to map editor tab, I cannot see my hosted layer. Also, when I click on the layer and click "Publish" (just to try) it says that is not possible as the item doesn't exist (but it actually does):

[image]

I tried to publish as GeoJSON and SHP, in private and in public mode, and always tick the "hosted layer" checkbox when upload but nothing has worked.

Why are my hosted layers are not usable?

Comment: How large is your geoJSON file / how many features does your shapefile have? Generally speaking, your workflow sounds fine. It's a matter of figuring out why you can't turn your data into a hosted service.

Comment: @KHibma My file has about 24.000 items (that basically are squares 50mtx50mt distributed on an area of 6.000 km²) , each record has 2 columns: an id-column and a legend (varchar). Do you think it may be a "question of time"? Thanks!

Comment: Best guess -- it's a lot of data and the backend processes are trying to turn 24,000 features into a hosted service. I can't guess how long it _should_ take, but I'd let it work for 5-10minutes and come back. If it hasn't created the service by then, I'm not sure what else to try? The number of attributes is fine, just 24,000 polygons might be what's tripping the process up.

Comment: I guess I did it! I have created a file containing just 1 point, in order to see if it would work and it did (feature layer created immediately). Right after, I tried to "publish" the bigger layer and it did it instantly, it was like stucked or something similar!

Comment: So you're good to go? I'd suggest putting an answer on and accepting it. Otherwise this could be closed as no longer reproducible.